# Integrating TestComplete scripts in maven build

Tags: maven, testcomplete

We use TestComplete as testing framework and our testers has written a number of scripts for testing. The idea is to run this scripts during the night build, which is executed as maven script. Has someone succeeded to combine these two technologies?

Comment: i have no experience with TestComplete, but is there any reason that a maven profile with an invocation of the exec plugin wont work ?

Comment: No, but generally the idea was to execute TestComplete scripts directly, not just to call to execute TestComplete from maven. Similar opportunity exists for Jenkins - there is a TestComplete plugin, but not for maven.

Comment: personally i strive to make maven do everything (even calling scripts via execute plugin) and then make jenkins a "dumb ui" for maven (make it run maven with the appropriate profiles). that makes maven the one place for all build options, as opposed to spreading it across maven and jenkins (and commit hooks, and god knows what else)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should be possible. However, since TestComplete is an UI automated testing tool, you need to make sure that your TestComplete test is launched in an interactive UI session. So, you need to have a user that is used to run the Maven script logged on the to the test machine and the machine should not be locked.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are an azure user. You can create a pipeline and automate your test cases overnight.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).